# .htaccess password protect directory but allow image file types

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to password protect a directory with .htaccess, which I have successfully done.  But the front end of the website was programmed to link to images within this password protected directory (not by me), but when a webpage tries to access those images it prompts the user to login.

Is it possible to password protect that directory, but allow any access to any image file type like *.jpg and *.gif?

My current .htaccess code is this:

```
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/siteuser/.htpasswds/public_html/admin/passwd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/siteuser/.htpasswds/public_html/admin/passwd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$">
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Edit to incorporate Shef's improvement

Comment: +1. Short & Sweet! Though the regex should be changed to match only from the end of the string `FilesMatch "\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check all the different options of configuration .htaccess gives you in the following site:

[Stupid htaccess Tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try put it inside Filematch?

```
<FilesMatch "^.*(png|jpe?g|gif)$">
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/siteuser/.htpasswds/public_html/admin/passwd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: this won't work. it secures images but NOT other documents. Opposite of what OP want

Answer (score -1):

What you could try is to write an image display proxy:

- Keep the directory like you have it now, with password protection.
- On the .htaccess on the root of the website where the images are linked, add a Rewrite rule for those image types you want. This rule should redirect the call to a PHP handler script.
- That script should evaluate the path that was being requested, load the file from the filesystem, deduct its header and send that to the client using `header()`, followed by the image file's content `echo file_get_contents()`should do.

PHP is not affected by the .htaccess so it should be able to read the file you need and proxy it to the end user.