# .htaccess - deny from all, excludes images

Tags: image, .htaccess

How I can create .htaccess file, When I wanna disable all files except images.
My code.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess password protect directory but allow image file types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863162/htaccess-password-protect-directory-but-allow-image-file-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787586/htaccess-allowing-access-files-by-extension).

For example you can use the following:

```
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
   order deny,allow
   allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: order allow,deny
    <Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|txt|bmp)$">
       allow from all
    </Files>

Comment: yes, of course you can add all the extensions you want and use the internal logic you need ;)

Comment: The code will in-fact not prevent access to other content, because the command will only be executed when the patter matches (and will allow anyway).  It should rather be:     order allow,deny
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|txt)$">
 allow from all
</Files>

Answer (score 10):

Tx you, My final code

```
order allow,deny
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf|txt|bmp)$">
   allow from all
</Files>
```